# Manipulating the Time Slider Widget?

Tags: arcgis-online, timeslider

My organization is looking to manipulate the time slider widget to do the following:

1. Not show the "play button"-- is there a way to turn this feature off?
2. Show time in a single year (YYYY) format. We are only able to show time in an interval format of YYYY - YYYY,   despite selecting the YYYY format option.

Any thoughts or advice on these items would be great.